# Night mode is applied for Android app after app goes to background and resumes

Tags: android, material-components-android

recently found a problem on our app that app after resuming from background applies dark mode, but before that light mode is forced, any ideas how to solve it?

Theme:

```
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge with android:forceDarkAllowed = false



In Activity onCreate() is used AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
```

Also it happens only to some of the colors, mostly black.

Any ideas what could be wrong? It was working fine before some time, all colours was forced to light.

Comment: Did you find something to fix it? 
I have the same issue...

Comment: yes, created same colours just with different names and it worked, still not sure what is the actual problem.